# Integration of several mobile ad networks with Admob Mediation

Tags: android, networking, admob, revmob, leadbolt

I want to integrate following mobile ad networks in my android app.

1. Admob
2. Revmob
3. Leadbolt
4. Amazon Api

   I have searched a lot and finally come to know by using customevents in admob mediation can integrate mobile ads. But I dont know how to do it.I searched in google developer site they provide sample code for admob.But I dont know how main activity reference the custom events?

Can anyone provide me the sample source code for integrating anyother mobile ad network with admob mediation?

Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

It is clearly explained in this section. Try following this. It'll work just fine.

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/custom-events

The details are very clear. All the best

EDIT: Updated the link. Thanks Tough Guy

Comment: Probably you wanted to point out to this address. Kindly update your answer.
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/custom-events